# Does software exist to log all download / upload usage?

Tags: windows-xp, bandwidth

Does a program exist to record all upload / download usage for a personal computer?

So I can reset it at some stage, and then use the internet, and then look at how much data has been sent/received?

Comment: Any SNMP software will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a little Delphi program I found for specifics like this, appropriately named [Network Traffic Monitor](http://delphi.about.com/od/fullcodeprojects/l/aa112903a.htm). It does pretty much all you need, and that's about it really.

[image]

Comment: When you close it though, it seems to reset all TOTALs to 0. :S

Answer (score 2):

**[Bandwidth Monitor](http://www.rokario.com/products/bandmon/2-0/)** should do what you need. The Lite edition is free.

> An ideal tool for the bandwidth conscious, Bandwidth Monitor enables you to keep a close eye on the amount of bandwidth accumulated over the current hour, day, week, month, or even year! Advanced logging tools make it easy to view your bandwidth usage and make alterations to bandwidth logs. Clean up old data at the touch of a button, and import your bandwidth data from our predecessor Bandwidth Monitor 1.0.

Alternatively there's **[FreeMeter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemeter/)**, if you prefer something with an Open Source flavour. To view the log, you need to right-click the meter (or the tray icon), then select **Utilties > Totals Log**. In the Counter tab, there's a reset button.

[image: FreeMeter]

Answer (score 2):

[DU Meter](http://www.dumeter.com/) does all of this however it is not free.

The features for DU-Meter include:

- Provides clear graphical and/or numerical display
- Reporting facility with export to
  many different file formats,
  including HTML, Excel, PDF and others
- Permits close supervision of uploads
  and downloads
- Compatible with all network
  interfaces: Dial-Up, Cable, ADSL,
  Ethernet, and others
- Fully compatible with Windows Vista,
  Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 and
  Windows 2000
- Requires minimal screen real estate
  and system resources
- Involves no changes to your Windows
  system files
- Auto-hide feature minimizes the meter
  to the system tray in the absence of
  network activity
- Option to notify user or disconnect
  from the Internet automatically when
  network activity drops below a certain level
- Useful stopwatch to accurately time
  downloads and report the average
  transfer rates

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a lot of programs that can do this, I have had good success with [Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/).

It has a Speed Meter Timer (that acts like a stopwatch) for measuring bandwidth usage from the moment you click start to stop. You can also enter quota information for your internet plan.

- A good free Internet monitoring tool
- Small footprint
- 64-bit flavor

Answer (score 0):

[wipfw](http://wipfw.sourceforge.net) can count the traffic that passes through a network interface.

> **What is WIPFW?**
>
> WIPFW is a MS Windows operable version of IPFW for FreeBSD OS. You can
>   use the same functionality and configure it as only you work with
>   IPFW.
>
> IPFW is a packet filtering and accounting system which resides in the
>   kernelmode, and has a user-land control utility, ipfw. Together, they
>   allow you to define and query the rules used by the kernel in its
>   routing decisions.
>
> There are two related parts to ipfw. The firewall section performs
>   packet filtering. There is also an IP accounting section which tracks
>   usage of the router, based on rules similar to those used in the
>   firewall section. This allows the administrator to monitor how much
>   traffic the router is getting from a certain machine, or how much WWW
>   traffic it is forwarding, for example.
>
> As a result of the way that ipfw is designed, you can use ipfw on
>   non-router machines to perform packet filtering on incoming and
>   outgoing connections. This is a special case of the more general use
>   of ipfw, and the same commands and techniques should be used in this
>   situation.

Answer (score 0):

[NetLimiter Monitor](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php) does this very well.

> NetLimiter is an ultimate internet traffic control and monitoring tool designed for Windows. You can use NetLimiter to set download/upload transfer rate limits for applications or even single connection and monitor their internet traffic.
>
> Along with this unique feature, Netlimiter offers comprehensive set of internet statistical tools. It includes real-time traffic measurement and long-term per-application internet traffic statistics
>
> [image]