# Ubuntu tool for showing internet traffic for each process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internet, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find out what application using most of bandwidth in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/32932/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-application-using-most-of-bandwidth-in-linux)

Is there any Linux tool that shows each process usage of internet bandwidth

such as :

```
    chromium use 20 KB/s 
    Firefox  use 10 KB/s
```

and if there is a plug-in for system monitor, please show me it .

thanks...

Comment: very similar to [How can I monitor network usage by process on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/354215/how-can-i-monitor-network-usage-by-process-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Cool. This is like top only for network traffic. Lets one pin down PID and troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 1):

you can try "ntop" but it is a command line tool.

Comment: ntop has a webgui to