# application that could track amount of downloads

Tags: windows, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does software exist to log all download / upload usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/15442/does-software-exist-to-log-all-download-upload-usage)
>   [How to keep below my bandwidth download cap and why does my ISP have such a huge difference in reported downloads from my monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/89569/how-to-keep-below-my-bandwidth-download-cap-and-why-does-my-isp-have-such-a-huge)
>   [Software to report internet traffic for home user](https://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user)

My ISP only limits me for downloading about 25gb a month. After exceeding the limit, my speed goes down by half for another month. And its really a pain.  I'm real addicted on downloading stuff from the internet. My question is:

1. Is there an application that can track the amount/size of downloads in a month.
2. Is there a trick that I could use to fool the eyes of my ISP.
3. If they say 25 Gb limit in a month. Does it include the webpages, manga streams, video & audio streams. Or just direct download and p2p.

Comment: Yea, I wouldn't go with anything for #2 as your ISP may terminate your service for doing that.  Plus its illegal and of course, probably goes against your ISP's ToS.

Comment: As for #3, everything you do is a "download" in the eyes of your ISP, as you're getting bits from the internet through their line.

Comment: ow what a drag.

Comment: 1: http://superuser.com/questions/15442/does-software-exist-to-log-all-download-upload-usage 2: No 3: Includes everything

Answer (score 1):

For starters i can recommend the software [**"netlimiter"**](http://www.netlimiter.com/) for measuring the bandwidth you used in a certain time [like today/last week/last month/etc]. When you think you are getting close to your limit, you are also able to limit the speed so you won't go over the limit too fast, and stay connected the remainder of the month.

I would really not bother trying to fool your provider, it might result in getting cut off or huge bills arriving at your door (They can charge crazy amounts of excess bandwidth)

And for number 3 i can only give you an idication, since most providers have a download limit which is fixed for everything you do. So sending/receiving mails to using websites and so on will all be in that limit. But some providers want to limit only specific kinds of use, for example my provider(mobile phone) limits the use of streaming video/audio to about 5GB a month though i can visit websites as much as i like.
My home ISP limits me with a Fair-Use-Policy and the office ISP uses a limit of 50GB after which i get set back on a lower speed.

I suggest you call your ISP/search their website for more exact details about this. you might just be lucky

Answer (score 0):

1. There are some applications that can track download (and upload) volumes.
   Some of them make errors so you should include that in your arithmetic.
2. You cannot fool your ISP in this accounting
3. A download limit counts all downloads,
   this includes files, pages, images and also ads that your browser downloads.

   - Besides this, your Windows system would also be doing automatic updates.
   - In some places/ISPs, the limit is actually on the sum of your uploads and downloads.
     In these cases, the web requests that you send out also count!

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent, free application, is  [NetWorx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) It allows yo to set quotas and provides statistics for hourly, daily and monthly usage. It also provides information on upload/download speed and other network related information.