# How can I find out how many bytes are sent and received when browsing?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, bandwidth, network-monitoring, network-traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does software exist to log all download / upload usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/15442/does-software-exist-to-log-all-download-upload-usage)

I have a 3G dongle and it shows bytes sent and received when I browse.

Is there a software for Windows XP which I can run on my machine which shows the same thing, but for a normal network? For example, when I click on a button on a web site.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: I want the ability to set it to 0 and then click on a website. i would prefer a septate software

Comment: Your operating system would be a helpful thing to know...

Comment: To clarify, are you running Windows, ubuntu, mac, debian...? Until you answer, I can't find a program for you.

Comment: i am using windows xp

Answer (score 1):

Open task manager, and go to the network tab. Click view, show columns, select total sent and total received. When you want to see how much a given web site will take up, close task manager if its open, open it, load the page, read the numbers, close the page. Make sure you have nothing else running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install firefox then download [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bandwidth-meter-and-diagnostic/) bandwidth monitor plugin:

then Open "Tools" menu and click the item "Bandwidth Meter". You can perform upload and download bandwidth measurements till the cows come home.

Comment: i would like it not to be restricted to one browser

Answer (score 0):

If you look at properties on the network connection in the control panel, it has up/down counters. I think they are even updated live.